# I can't get pythonTEX to work, too few arguments

Tags: python

I have tried to get the `pythontex` package to work in LaTeX but I get the typical(?)  output, after I ran LaTeX, the python code and the LaTeX again. Then I found that I get "`pythontex.py`: error: too few arguments" when I run the code. So I guess I'll have to give in the name of the `pythontex` code but where?

```
\documentclass[oneside]{memoir}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pythontex}
\begin{document}
\py{2+2}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I get no error.

Comment: Are you running something like `pythontex doc.tex`? This looks like what happens when `pythontex.py` isn't getting the name of the  document.

Comment: BTW: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: @egreg do you just run the pythontex.py or do you give it the texfile as argument because it won't accept any argument I give.

Comment: I called the file `candela.tex` and ran `pdflatex candela`, then `pythontex candela`, then `pdflatex candela` again.

Comment: @egreg thanks, it is working now, how can I accept your comment as answer? I don't see the option.

Answer (score 2):

If the file is `candela.tex`, you have to run

```
pdflatex candela
pythontex candela
pdflatex candela
```

Running `pythontex` is not necessary if no change to the Python code have been made between a run of `pdflatex` and the next one.